# How is it possible that so many words seem to get the exact opposite meaning when adopted to a different language?

Tags: english, swedish

"Semester" in Swedish means "vacation". In English, "semester" means the exact opposite: the time period of the year when you are in school. I don't know which stole the word from which, or if it's a sheer coincidence, but this is far from the first time I've encountered this.

Sadly, I can't think of any more examples right now, but I do know that they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The English word '[semester](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semester#Etymology)' comes from German *Semester* which comes from New Latin *sēmestris* (“lasting six months”), from *sex* (“six”) + *mēnsis* (“month”), and Swedish '[semester](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semester#Etymology_5)' was probably borrowed directly from New Latin. Both the English meaning "half of a school year or academic year" and the Swedish meaning "a holiday/vacation, especially from work" are secondary, developed later, although American English [still keeps](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/semester) the original meaning "a six-month period; half year".

As for the opposite meaning which is called *antonymy* in linguistics, even within a single language one can find words which mean two opposite things at the same time, just remember the English word *awesome* which means both "inducing awe/respect" and "cool, splendid", such a word is called [*auto-antonym* or *autantonym*, *contronym*, *contranym* or *Janus word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym). If a word in a certain language can develop two opposite meanings, it is no surprise that when a word is borrowed by two different languages with different cultures and histories behind them, each language uses the word in its own way. And you are right, this phenomenon is not limited only to the word *semester*, it is widespread across the languages of the world.

Comment: i do not see how inducing respect is opposite to being splendid

Comment: Really bad things can induce respect, like “awful” which has better retained this meaning

Answer (score 0):

Some instances of confusion might stem from a particular choice of words by the translator reinterpreting the false friend, to highlight the difference. As in your case, English *semester* is simply not the opposite of *vacation*.

So it further depends on cultural connotation. I'm sure you know about the vastly different meanings of the N-word, for example.

This is of course easier to observe between disparate culturul groups (in fact, they are a good measure for the existence of such divisions). But a good number of auto-antonyms of various degree within one language are notable as well; many more, if considering technical speech as part of the language, as for legalese for example.

---

By the way: German has *Bildungsurlaub* (*education vacation* [=sabbatical]), that's has no contradictory semantics itself, although *Urlaub* itself is chiefly synonymous with more formulaic *Erholungsurlaub* (recreational leave).